# Custom React GUI for oidc-client-js

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

is there a way to user your custom React GUI with [oidc-client-js](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js)? I know that if you trigger authentication endpoint using:

```
            // PopUps might be blocked by the user, fallback to redirect
            try {
                await this.userManager.signinRedirect(this.createArguments(state)); //Shows midleware login form
                return this.redirect();
            } catch (redirectError) {
                console.log("Redirect authentication error: ", redirectError);
                return this.error(redirectError);
            }
```

Middleware will try to render its predefined login form:

[image: OIDC default form]

However I have my own React form and I only need to pass to OICDClient params (email,password) and get back User instance to display UserName etc. Something like:

```
var loggedUser = await this.userManager.signinCustom(state.loginEmail, state.LoginPassword); //Login using credentials
```

I don't want to write all the logic by myself I really want to use all functionality from OIDCClient - only with my GUI (loginForm, registerForm, updateUserForm etc).

I'm using [scaffolded library from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-5.0) using command:

```
dotnet new react -o <output_directory_name> -au Individual
```

Is there any method/implementation to initialise oidc-client-js from React components and not user default GUI forms?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: People do use IdentityServer with react/angular without MVC. Here is a thread https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1186.
 Further this medium article mentioned in the thread may be helpful.
https://medium.com/@piotrkarpaa/using-spa-react-angular-ui-with-identity-server-4-dc1f57e90b2c

Here is a youtube video link explaining the exact you asked for 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YF8coyfQb0Y&t=1660s

Answer (score 1):

I might be missing some thing but the whole idea of using a 3rd partly federated auth provider be it your own/your company's SSO (say developed using Identity Server 4) or say Google sign in(say using their Firebase JS kit) or Microsoft sign in, Facebook sign in etc. is that you will be redirected to their authentication endpoint where you then use say your google credentials (if you are using google sign in for example) to sign on to google auth servers. Once you do that then a payload (consisting of an identity token and access token) is returned back to your redirect URL which you must configure for your specific app.

By saying you'd like to provide your own sign-in form you are missing the entire point of using a 3rd party authentication provider. Besides, you/your app shouldn't know about user names and passwords and you don't want to have access to all that information. All that you should be interested in knowing whether the user, who are using one of the federated authentication providers, that you would have configured for your app, are who they claim to be and you then delegate all that heavy lifting to your 3rd party authentication provider.

Besides, say your company has a SSO system of their own then all your company's  app will use that SSO system and from a UI perspective you want to show the same login screen so as to give a consistent user experience.

In addition, if you show me a google authentication button and then on clicking that button you show me some weird form that doesn't look like the typical google picklist sign-in form then I'll shut down your app before you can say hello, and, I suspect most user would (and should) do the same. The reason being that when you show me a google sign-in page then I know that you/your app will only get back what you need and I wouldn't ever entrust my google user name and password to *any* other application.

If you really want to have your own authentication form then you'll have to manage user names and passwords yourself, the way we used to do things probably over 10+ years back.

If you decide to go the route of setting up your own authentication system and then say use identity server 4 then yes you can certainly change the UI and customize it to your heart's content, but that will happen at the server level, not at the level of your react app. Point being that in any SSO system the user will be redirected to the that auth provider's endpoint where they then authenticate (and, optionally, provider permission for your app to use certain claims) and once they do that they they are redirected back to your redirect endpoint with a payload (JWT token).

Lastly, even if you could some how wire up a client side sign in form, I'm not sure you would want to use it. Passing passwords & user names over the wire isn't a good idea. You'll always want to use a server rendered sign in form.